# Create an array of mocks using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I'm trying to make a separate method for creating a list of mocks. E.g. we have a class `Entity`:

```
class Entity {
    public List<SubEntity> subEntities;
}
```

But `SubEntity` is interface which has two implementations:

```
class SubEntityA implements SubEntity {
    public SomeType someProp;
}
```

and

```
class SubEntityB implements SubEntity {
    public SomeAnotherType someAnotherProp;
}
```

so I can have in `subEnities` property a mixed list of `SubEntityA` and `SubEntityB` objects.

In real case I have more then two types and I'd like to write a test where I need to generate a different amount of mocks of this classes and add it to the property `subEntities`. I can easily crate one mock using:

```
mock(SubEntityA.class)
```

but when I'm trying to do something like this:

```
private List<SubEntity> getMocks(Class<? extends SubEntity> classToMock, int amount) {
    List<SubEntity> mocks = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        mocks.add(mock(classToMock));
    }
    return mocks;
}
```

I get into trouble using e.g. `List<SubEntityA> list = getMocks(SubEntityA.class, 3)`, because `SubEntityA.class` or `SubEntityB.class` couldn't be casted to `Class<? extends SubEntity>`.

What I'm doing wrong? What shall I do to pass classes properly? I tried to find Mockito's methods  but found only `Mockito.anyListOf`. As I understood It won't work in my case.

Thanks!

[UPD] The test looks like:

```
@Mock
private RepoSubA repoA;

@Mock
private RepoSubB repoB;

@Mock
private Repo repo;

@InjectMocks    
private LogicBean testee;

@Test
public void test() {
    //given
    List<SubEntityA> listA = getMocks(SubEntityA.class, 3);
    List<SubEntityB> listB = getMocks(SubEntityB.class, 3);
    List<SubEntity> list = new ArraList<>();
    list.addAll(listA);
    list.addAll(listB);

    Rule rule = someFixture();
    when(repoA.getA(rule.getId())).thenReturn(listA);
    when(repoB.getB(rule.getId())).thenReturn(listB);

    //when
    List<SubEntity> result = testee.someMagic(rule);

    //then
    assertThat(result, hasSize(list.size());
}
```

Comment: `getMocks(SubEntityA.class, amount) ` will perfectly compile. Besides, you don't perform any cast in your code. Please share the full stracktrace.

Comment: @davidxxx There's just one error: `Error:(101, 84) java: incompatible types: java.util.List<model.SubEntity> cannot be converted to java.util.List<model.SubEntotyA>`

Comment: Unfortunately, I should create different lists for each type and then add them to `subEntities`.

Comment: Since `SubEntity` is an interface, why does it matter the actual type?  Is there some instanceof/casting going on which is making testing harder?

Comment: Yes, It matters, because I also need to mock results of repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to get the error but failed.  This is the code I wrote.

```
public static class Entity {

    public List<SubEntity> subEntities;
}

public static class SubEntityA implements SubEntity {

}

public static class SubEntityB implements SubEntity {

}

private List<? extends SubEntity> getMocks(Class<? extends SubEntity> classToMock, int amount) {
    List<SubEntity> mocks = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        mocks.add(mock(classToMock));
    }
    return mocks;
}

@Test
public void test(){
    assertEquals(3, getMocks(SubEntityA.class, 3).size());
    List<SubEntityA> mocks = (List<SubEntityA>) getMocks(SubEntityA.class, 3);
    assertEquals(3, getMocks(SubEntityB.class, 3).size());
}
```

I then executed Junit on the test method.  The test passed.

EDIT:  To respond to your comment, you can change the signature of your getmocks method so that the output could be cast to `List<SubEntityA>`.  I edited my code above and the cast works.

Comment: There are troubles with casting from `List<SubEntity>` to `List<SubEntityA> list`. The result of `getMocks(...)` should be set to `when(repo.getEntitiesA()).thenReturn(list)`.

Comment: I used the code in your question.  Was there more code that you did not include?  If so, can you please include that code and be specific as to where the error is occurring.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I've provided example of test in question.

Comment: It works! Now the test could be much more pretty! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Following is more strict and consistent as you use just the same class for return list type.

```
private static <T extends SubEntity> List<T> getMocks(Class<T> classToMock, int amount) {
    List<T> mocks = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        mocks.add(mock(classToMock));
    }
    return mocks;
}
```